# Windows 10 environment variable PATH not getting updated

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

Inspired by the following video link :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQ58d3BEV_8

I tried to change the PATH variable of my system  and add the path that has been mentioned there .

Ii have a windows 10 System . I first went to "view advanced system settings" , there I found "PATH" listed under both "User variables" and " Environment Variables " .

I clicked on both of them , then clicked on new and pasted the following :

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727"

and clicked on Ok . On clicking on these two variables I could find the path listed but on closing "advanced system settings" and opening it again I could not find them .

I opened a new session of "COmmand Prompt " and tried to display the value of PATH as 
"echo %PATH%" 
but still the same result . The path that I had added did not get added .

So , I tried doing it through Regedit . I modified the PATH variable but on opening the command prompt and displaying PATH variable did not reflect any changes .

What can be the reason behind this ? How can I get to use csc.exe as in the video link ?

Please let me know if any further details are required

Comment: Only add that in System Variable for all user. The video is old. Windows 10 has .NET v4.7.1. So you may add `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`  for 32bit or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` for 64bit. Also restart PC to take effect.

Comment: @Biswapriyo : Ok would try . Hhave you tried it earlier ?